# Changing Visual C++ output of inf

Tags: c++, visual-c++, io

In Visual C++, if I have a double with the value inf, and I output it using a stream:

```
double myval = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
std::ostringstream msg;
msg << "This is infinite: " << myval;
```

The result is "1.#INF".

Is there an easy way to make it print simply "inf" or "INF"? This string appears in text that will subsequently be parsed, and extra characters are causing us problems.

I thought of overloading the stream operator for double, but double is a built-in type.

I confess I can't figure out exactly how to search for an answer to the basic question...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but somewhat non-trivial, and the correct way to do it is fairly obscure.

As an aside, I'll note that when you do something like `msg << myval;` only *one* of the operands has to be a user-defined type, which is the case here (even though *you* didn't define it, an `ostringstream` is still officially a user-defined type). That's more or less irrelevant though. The existing overload of `operator<<` will work fine; you don't need to provide your own.

I think of a stream as a "matchmaker". You have a stream buffer to handle the actual I/O, and a locale to handle the formatting. Thinking of things that way, the solution becomes fairly clear: since what you want to change is the formatting, and formatting is handled by a locale, you need to change the locale.

A locale, however, is really a heterogeneous collection. Specifically, it's a collection of `facet` classes. In this case, the facet we care about is the `num_put` facet. The num_put facet class has virtual `do_put` member functions for various types. The one we care about in this case is `double`:

```
template <class charT, class OutputIterator = std::ostreambuf_iterator<charT> >
class num_put : public std::num_put<charT, OutputIterator> {
public:
    virtual iter_type do_put(iter_type i, 
                             std::ios_base& b, 
                             char_type fill, 
                             double v) const 
    {
        if (v == std::numeric_limits<double>().infinity()) {
            static const char inf[]="inf";      
            std::copy(std::begin(inf), std::end(inf), i);
        }
        else {
            std::ostringstream temp;
            temp << v;
            std::copy(temp.str().begin(), temp.str().end(), i);
        }
        return i;           
    }
};
```

To use it, you imbue the stream in question with a locale that includes that facet:

```
int main() {
    char *d="0";

    std::locale loc(std::locale::classic(), new num_put<char>);
    std::cout.imbue(loc);

    std::cout << 1.0/atoi(d);
    return 0;
}
```

I should add, however, that this was slapped together pretty quickly, and testing is *extremely* minimal. It works for the test case, and probably for other narrow streams. At a guess, it probably needs more work before it'll work correctly with a wide stream though.